# Почему не получается получить изображение с помощью requests?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, изображения, requests

**upd:** перезагрузка библиотеки requests магическим образом разрешила проблему

Программа проходит по нескольким URL, для каждой выводит изображение в байтах. На некоторых изображениях (пример такого изображения привел ниже) итерация прерывается и не идет дальше.
Что может быть причиной такой проблемы? Как от нее избавиться?

Код:

```
# изображение, которое невозможно получить
URL = 'https://persons-info.com/userfiles/image/persons/70000-80000/78000-79000/78406/KLUTSIS_Gustav_Gustavovich14.jpg'

img = requests.get(URL).content

print(img)
```

Результат:

Comment: Проблема повторяется в cmd.exe / wt.exe / etc?

Comment: а код ответа какой?

Comment: @alex `img = requests.get(url=url)       print(img.status_code)` Ничего не выводит

Comment: @ShamusRezol Я не понял вашего вопроса

Comment: @JoshJohnson, вы запускаете скрипт из IDE pycharm (не имею представления о  нем)? Если запустить скрипт из командной строки (cmd.exe) на подобие "python3.exe script.py", то проблема повторяется?

Comment: запросил через requests ваш url, получил <Response [200]> и содержимое байтами сразу, а в браузере долго думало, прежде чем открыть изображение... думаю, дело в сайте, нужно изучать

Comment: @Jack_oS удалось решить проблему перезагрукой requests ))))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное у вас из-за большого количества данных в байтах вам ничего не показало, но попробуйте просто записать фото вот код:

```py
import requests
URL = 'https://persons-info.com/userfiles/image/persons/70000-80000/78000-79000/78406/KLUTSIS_Gustav_Gustavovich14.jpg'

img = requests.get(URL).content



f = open('foto.png','wb')
f.write(img)
f.close()
```

В чате обсудили, после переустановки модуля с помощью команд:
1)`pip uninstall requests`
2)`pip install requests`
Стало всё работать.

Comment: Ничего не происходит.

Comment: Посмотрите папку с вашим скриптом.У вас должен появиться файл foto.png

Comment: В папке ничего нет

Comment: Простите, а вы скачали правильно requests?

Comment: Да, у меня скачен этот модуль

Comment: Попробуйте написать это в консоле
1)`pip uninstall requests`
2)`pip install requests`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119464/discussion-between---and-joshjohnson).